# Perl 6 transforms combined graphemes?

Tags: raku

How is it possible that two codepoints are transformed into one? And if it's the default way of treating combined graphemes, how to avoid it?

```perl6
> my $a = "a" ~ 0x304.chr
ā
> $a.codes
1
> $a.ords
(257)
```

UPD: Upon reading the [documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/unicode#File_Handles_and_I/O) I see that already all the input is normalized:

> Perl6 applies normalization by default to all input and output except
> for file names which are stored as UTF8-C8.

So, is there a method to avoid the normalization, i.e. to get the input and to treat it without any changes in the encoding?

Comment: Some characters have two Unicode representations: one that is a combined character with a unique entry and one that is a result of multiple codepoints. This is where NFD/NFC and the like are important. Look at [this](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) for more.

Comment: @callyalater, if I'm not mistaken, I need NFD here? Is there a(n easy) way to switch it on in my case?

Comment: Yes, NFD will always decompose the characters into all its codepoints. You just use the `NFD` conversion method and call `codes` on that. ie `$a.NFD.codes`. See [this](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2017-10-19#i_15327080) as an example.

Comment: @callyalater, and how can I get `ords` for the `NFD` representation of `$a`?

Comment: `$a.NFD.list` will give you a list of all the codepoints in the NFD object.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Maybe you'll merge all this info and make an answer? In my current work it's indeed very useful.

Comment: @callyalater, sorry, I've somehow misunderstood the explanation.  `$a.NFD.codes` gives `2` even if `$a` contains a symbol with only one codepoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a Unicode report (see [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms)), some characters have multiple ways of being represented. Per that report:

> Certain characters are known as singletons. They never remain in the text after normalization. Examples include the angstrom and ohm symbols, which map to their normal letter counterparts a-with-ring and omega, respectively.
>
> ...
>
> Many characters are known as canonical composites, or precomposed characters. In the D forms, they are decomposed; in the C forms, they are *usually* precomposed.

In the example you provided, `$a` contains a string that can be represented in two ways. First, it corresponds to U+0101 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH MACRON) which is a Unicode codepoint. Second, it can be represented as two codepoints that combine to form an equivalent character (U+0061 [LATIN SMALL LETTER A] followed by U+0304 [COMBINING MACRON]).

These two representations are the basis for NFC and NFD. These are called *normalized* forms because they allow characters to be regularly represented using either the most concise or most deconstructed representation available. Some combined characters may have two entries in the Unicode table (such as Ohm and Big Omega), but the normalized form maps to only one entry.

NFD decomposes all of the characters into a list of all the codepoints used to make those characters, making sure not to use the precomposed character instead.

Perl6 automatically uses the NFC representation, but you can get the NFD (or **D**ecomposed) version by using the `NFD` conversion method on `Str`.

```
my $a = "a" ~ 0x304.chr;

say $a.codes;                 # OUTPUT: 1
                              # This is because the concatenation
                              # is using NFC by default.
say $a.ords;                  # OUTPUT: (257)

say $a.NFD.codes;             # OUTPUT: 2
say $a.NFD.list;              # OUTPUT: (97 772)
```

NFC and NFD are both useful, but are intended for distinct purposes. As far as I can tell, there is no way to avoid normalization on input, but you can convert the input to whichever representation you need using the `NFC` and `NFD` conversion methods.

Comment: An exhaustive answer, as usual! And yet I wonder, whether there might be a way to avoid normalization on input... :)

Comment: @evb Currently, it does not look like it is possible to avoid normalization on string input (see the #perl6 irc chat [here](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2017-10-19#i_15327401)).

Comment: in my opinion it's a serious drawback. Hope it'll be be implemented in future.

Comment: @evb Currently you can use `utf8-c8` which should allow round-tripping of data. (You need to use it on both the input and output) In the future it may be possible to read into a Uni which will be more Stringy than a Buf. You could also just read data in as binary.